# Google Play Services Admob Banner

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I inserted google play services library in my application and I have integrated admob banner. My phone's internet connection is closed but it shows black and banner doesn't hidden. How can  I do?

[image]

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {       

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 

        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.reklam);
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Request for Ads
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        //.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        //.addTestDevice("")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);


         MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
           final ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
             myPager.setAdapter(adapter);            
             myPager.setCurrentItem(25); 
             myPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

             Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnext);
             next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     myPager.setCurrentItem(myPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
                 }
             }); 

             Button duvarbtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
             duvarbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                 public void onClick(View v) {                   
                     int id=ListOfID[indexOfImage];
                    WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager
                     = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    try {                                                                      
                        myWallpaperManager.setResource(id);     
                        Toast.makeText(App.this, "Wallpaper has been set",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                 }          
             }); 
    }


      @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.resume();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
      }

      /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }

    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
        indexOfImage = position;
        switch (position) {
        case 0://
       firstpage(position);     
            break;
        case 51:
         firstpage(position);
            break;
        }

    }

    public void firstpage(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
         int pageCount = getCount();
         if (position == 0){
             //
             myPager.setCurrentItem(pageCount-2,false);
         } else if (position == pageCount-1){
            //ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
             myPager.setCurrentItem(1,false);
         }
    }

    private int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return count;
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //Filter f = (Filter) v.getTag();
       // MyPagerAdapter.show(this, input, f);
    }
    }
```

Layout xml;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="46dp"
        android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
        android:gravity="center" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonnext"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonprevious"
            android:background="@drawable/setaswallpaper" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/reklam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check first if there is internet connection. if not hide that view completely

Comment: If I remove MyPagerAdapter it hides auto

Answer (score 0):

Verify your internet connection:

```
    ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo mobileNetInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    NetworkInfo wifiNetInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    Boolean visible;

    if (wifiNetInfo != null && wifiNetInfo.isAvailable() && wifiNetInfo.isConnected()) {
        visible = true;
    }
    else if (mobileNetInfo != null && mobileNetInfo.isAvailable() && mobileNetInfo.isConnected()) {
        visible = true;
    }
    else
        visible = false

    layout.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE: View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

first check the internet connected or not then show the banner you can use that code for check internet conncetion

```
final ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final NetworkInfo info = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            final NetworkInfo info1 = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
             if (info.isConnected() | info1.isConnected()){
                //show the banner
             }else {
               //hide the banner
             }
```

dot forget to use below permission on the manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Change the Visibility of Layout to Gone

```
layout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

then write the below code for AdListner

```
adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onAdClosed();
                }


                @Override
                public void onAdLoaded() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onAdLoaded();
                    layout.addView(adView);
                    layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }


                @Override
                public void onAdOpened() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    super.onAdOpened();
                }

            });
```